# Error message when opening .ini file

Tags: autocmd

Vim shows the following long error message when I open a file with a dot-ini (.ini) file extension:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc[25]../usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syntax.vim[44]..BufRead Autocommands for "*~"..BufRead Autocommands for "*.ini"..FileType Autocommands for "*"..Syntax Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>3_SynSet[25]..script /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/dosini.vim: line 28: E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
```

Following that "\" on line 28 with any one of "/", "?" or "&" resulted in an even longer error message.

In my .zshenv:

```
export EDITOR=vim
export FCEDIT=vim
export SLANG_EDITOR=vim
```

Also:

````
--> vim --version                                                                     pts/2  Wednesday  2023-08-16  08:56:22 
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Aug 15 2023 20:47:29)
Included patches: 1-1713
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      +sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wdate-time -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vim-9Zy3tT/vim-9.0.0749+really.v9.0.1713=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: gcc -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lm -ltinfo -lselinux -lsodium -lacl -lattr -lgpm -L/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.10 -lcrypt -ldl -lm -lm```
````

`:set runtimepath?` shows:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/etc/vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim90/,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/etc/vim/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

Also, I have `vim-plug` the vim plugin manager in `~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim` but no plugins installed yet.

How can I get Vim to open .ini files without any error message(s)?

Comment: You shouldn't have to export `$VIM` or `$VIMRUNTIME` to begin with. Install Vim properly.

Comment: Why do you think I haven't installed Vim properly? Those are environment variables that are typically set in one's shell .env file, no?

Comment: No, you typically don't set them, *unless* you are trying to fix a bad install or trying to install stuff in weird places.

Comment: Thank you.  I see that indeed I don't need to set $VIMRUNTIME in order to have "echo $VIMRUNTIME" show me that it's at /usr/share/vim/vim90. I still don't understand why I get the busy error message when I open a .ini file. Implementing the suggestion in the message had no effect.

Comment: Could you add the full output of `$ vim --version` to the body of your question?

Comment: It seems to me that you have the trunk version of Vim. Do you have the same problem with some earlier version of Vim?

Comment: Trunk version as opposed to what? This is the only version of Vim I have, and I never tried to open a .ini file with earlier versions (except a patch-level or 2 previous to this one, with the same result).

Comment: Have you modified `/usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/dosini.vim`?

Comment: No. I attempted to modify it per the suggestion at the end of the error message, but that didn't help things, so I left that file with no change.

Comment: You are using a very latest version. See if it works when started with `vim --clean myconfg.ini`. If not, report an issue. Ref: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/dd0ad2598898c2b4641c4acd5b70b6184fa698ed

Comment: Starting vim with: 

sudo vim --clean /usr/share/im/vim90/syntax/dosini.vim

had no effect. Temporarily removing that file did, though I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: dosini syntax file changed recently.  I replied to your email in vim-dev mailing list and copied the dev of dosini syntax script.  They'll know more, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved by replacing the

`/usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/dosini.vim`

file dated ***2023 Jun 27***

with the one dated

***2023 Aug 20***

posted by Christian Brabandt here: https://groups.google.com/g/vim_use/c/9zccgo_RIqM

Thanks, Christian!